# Week of the day for current date in php

Tags: php, date

How do you find the date of the Monday for current date and the date of the Sunday of current date.

Comment: `date('l')` (lowercase L) will return the text representation of the day of the week. is that what you're asking for?

Comment: [use the search function before asking question please.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) All these trivial dateTime related questions have been asked and answered already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Monday this week'));
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Sunday this week'));
```

Comment: Thank! bro. I get right solution every time i asked but my question always vote down for my bad English.

Comment: @user1189157: the bad english is not the problem. many people here are not native english speakers.

Answer (score 0):

```
strtotime('next Monday')
```

I don't know what you mean by "the Monday for the current date" and "the Sunday of the current date."